# I want to allow only up to 100.000 in an input

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

```
function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt)
    {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

        var number = el.value.split('.');



        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        {
            return false;
        }
        //just one dot
        if (number.length > 1 && charCode == 46)
        {
            return false;
        }



        //get the carat position
        var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
        var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");
        if (caratPos > dotPos && dotPos > -1 && (number[1].length > 2))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //thanks: http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/
    function getSelectionStart(o)
    {
        if (o.createTextRange)
        {
            var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
            r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
            if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
            return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
        } else return o.selectionStart
    }

<td style="height:32px">
<input style="height:27px" name="hispanicLatino" class="numeral form-control text-font-md" type="text" oncopy="return false"
 oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" maxlength="100.000" onkeypress="return validateFloatKeyPress(this,event);" 
   data-bind="css: , attr: {id: 'hispanicLatino' + ($index() + 1), title: $parent.hispanicLatinoToolTip}, value: $data.hispanicLatino">
                                        </td>
```

> Updated my code. Now my code works to limit the decimals to 3 decimals after the "." but now the left part of the "." doesn't lock to 100. you can enter 1111111111 etc. Not sure what i should add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need immediate validation rather than only on submit you could try using a custom knockout binding to intercept the values before they're written to the view-model. This has the down-side of bypassing knockout's default textInput binding which handles a lot of browser specific quirks.

```js
//prevent values from updating unless they pass a validator function
ko.bindingHandlers.gatedValue = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    //element -> viewmodel
    var validator = allBindings().gatedValidator;
    $(element).on("keydown change keyup",
      function() {
        var newValue = $(element).val();
        var target = valueAccessor();
        if (validator(newValue)) {
          target(newValue);
        } else {
          $(element).val(target()); //reset to previous value
        }
      });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    //viewmodel -> element
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).val(value);
  }
}


function viewModel() {
  this.myNumber = ko.observable();
  this.myValidator = function(value) {
    var decimalPos = value.indexOf('.');
    if (decimalPos > 0) {
      var decimal = value.substring(decimalPos+1);
      if (decimal.length > 3) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    var numeric = Number(value);
    if (isNaN(numeric) || numeric > 100) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-bind="gatedValue: myNumber, gatedValidator: myValidator" />
```

Comment: I added this to my javascript file, I got an error says: 
"Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."

Comment: @TrEx You shouldn't be applying bindings multiple times

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure what does that mean and which other binding it is refering to. Would you please assist me.

Comment: @TrEx Do you have "ko.applyBindings" in more than one place?

Comment: I have none "ko.applyBindings" exactly.

Comment: @TrEx None? You must have at least one or knockout won't even run. That error gets thrown whenever knockout tries to initialize the same dom node more than once.

Comment: I just updated my answer. I use now a different function. it is good to make 3 decimals after the ".", but you can enter more than 100 in the left part of the ".". for example it only locks it when you enter the "." but you can enter 1001920102102 before the "." 

I appreciate you assistance. I have been stuck with this forever. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're relying on JavaScript here when it seems like native form controls would be sufficient.  Consider the following code:

```html
<form>
<input type="number" min="0.000" max="100.000" step=".001" required />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The minimum value is already set at `0.000` and the maximum at `100.000` with a step (the rate at which the number increases) set to `.001`.  Any value below the minimum or above the maximum will trigger a form error.

Certainly I would use JavaScript for adding clarity to the user, but in terms of raw "Make this form 'work'" it seems like HTML alone provides a solution.

Comment: It works but not exactly. I have a function for the format number. Would you help me with the code above to add something to limit it with only three digits decimal?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to limit the number of decimal places in your calculations? If that's the case you can try something like this in your code: `finalValue = ($(me).val() + currentValue).toFixed(3);`

Check this link for more info on the toFixed method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Thanks for helping @mike
The problem is when the person entering more than 3 digits decimal, the value would change based on making the approximate to the greater. For example: when i put 12.123 it stays like that which is great. When i Put 12.1234, the value would return to 12.234 because the fourth digit turns it to the greater. and cuts it. How could i stop that? Thnaks!